# I cannot reply to chat? why?

Tags: support

Please explain to me why I cannot answer to chat? people will think I don't want to reply to their oversimplification and false info about subject.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried joining the room by clicking the box on the right?

Comment: @StrongBad I dont understand you? How to join to something that I am already part of?

Comment: Does this link work: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73133/discussion-on-question-by-k99731-why-would-a-professor-say-in-pure-math-want-t

Comment: That's just bad UI. The "join this room" button is not where you would expect it (and is unnecessarily verbose).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screenshot in your question shows that you're looking at a chat *transcript*, which is read-only.

To participate in a chat room and reply to messages, click on the button on the right that says "Join this room" or "Join N users in this room". Once you have joined the chat room, there will be an input field at the bottom of the screen where you can write messages.

Comment: dear ff524, thank you for answer, but am I stupid or I dont see those options? "Join this room" or "Join N users in this room"

Comment: @SSimon look on the right side of your screen shot. There are three orange boxes on top of each other in the middle of the right side bar. The top one says "join 1 user in this room now".

Comment: @StrongBad thank you. I see now.